# Wiring parents/children in a direct acyclic graph in C++ with smart pointers causes SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, stdvector, smart-pointers

I'm trying to build a DAG in C++20. Each node has several children as well as parents. As a MWE, each node might compute some value.

Coming from the Java world, this code works as desired:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

abstract class AbstractDAGNode {

    List<AbstractDAGNode> children = new ArrayList<>();
    List<AbstractDAGNode> parents = new ArrayList<>();

    public AbstractDAGNode(List<AbstractDAGNode> children) {
        this.children = children;
        for (AbstractDAGNode child : children) {
            child.parents.add(this);
        }
    }

    public abstract double value();
}

class ValueDAGNode extends AbstractDAGNode {
    double value = 0;

    public ValueDAGNode(double value) {
        super(new ArrayList<>());
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public double value() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

class SumDAGNode extends AbstractDAGNode {

    public SumDAGNode(List<AbstractDAGNode> children) {
        super(children);
    }

    @Override
    public double value() {
        double result = 0;
        for (AbstractDAGNode child : children) {
            result += child.value();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class DAG {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ValueDAGNode v1 = new ValueDAGNode(1);
        ValueDAGNode v2 = new ValueDAGNode(2);
        SumDAGNode sum = new SumDAGNode(List.of(v1, v2));
        System.out.println(sum.value());
    }
}
```

However in C++ I'm getting `exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`, when using this code:

```cpp
class AbstractDAGNode {
protected:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractDAGNode>> children{};
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractDAGNode>> parents{};

public:
    explicit AbstractDAGNode(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractDAGNode>> children) {
        this->children = std::move(children);

        for (auto &child: this->children) {
            child->parents.emplace_back(this);
        }
    }

    virtual double Value() = 0;
};

class ValueDAGNode : public AbstractDAGNode {
protected:
    double value{};
public:
    explicit ValueDAGNode(double value) : AbstractDAGNode({}), value(value) {}

    double Value() override {
        return value;
    }
};

class SumDAGNode: public AbstractDAGNode {
public:
    explicit SumDAGNode(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractDAGNode>> &children) : AbstractDAGNode(children) {}

    double Value() override {
        double result = 0;
        for (auto &child: children) {
            result += child->Value();
        }
        return result;
    }
};

TEST_CASE("dag1") {
    std::shared_ptr<ValueDAGNode> v1 = std::make_shared<ValueDAGNode>(1);
    std::shared_ptr<ValueDAGNode> v2 = std::make_shared<ValueDAGNode>(2);

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractDAGNode>> children = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AbstractDAGNode>>{v1, v2};

    std::shared_ptr<SumDAGNode> sum_node = std::make_shared<SumDAGNode>(children);
}
```

The problem is apparently somewhere around here

```cpp
for (auto &child: this->children) {
    child->parents.emplace_back(this);
}
```

where I'm adding the current node to parents of each child. There's a warning `warning: delete called on 'AbstractDAGNode' that is abstract but has non-virtual destructor` but I don't know what that means or how to fix that.

Comment: `child->parents.emplace_back(this)`. This part is wrong. It takes a raw pointer and constructs a shared pointer from it - at which point you have two separate independent `shared_ptr` instances, with independent reference counts, both thinking they manage the same object. In any case, you likely don't want both `parents` and `children` to be `shared_ptr` - this way, you'll have a circular reference that would prevent any node from ever being deleted; the whole graph would leak. You probably want `children` to be `shared_ptr` and `parents` to be raw pointers.

Comment: To simplify; `int* raw = new int; std::shared_ptr<int> s1(raw);` OK so far. `std::shared_ptr<int> s2 = s1;` Still good - two `shared_ptr` instances manage the same object via the same refcount. `std::shared_ptr<int> s3 = raw;` This is a problem - now you have two sets of `shared_ptr` and two refcounts, all managing the same object. When either refcount goes to zero, the object is destroyed, and the other set of `shared_ptr` will end up holding a dangling pointer.

Comment: You can use [`shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) facility to make your program not crash, but again, you'll just replace the crash with a memory leak. You need a design that avoids circular references through owning pointers.

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to model this in C++. I think you're better off having an explicit `Graph` instance that owns all of the vertices. The vertices can then have non-owning pointers to each other.

Comment: Regarding *Coming from the java world*, note that C++ works quite differently not everything is reference semantics and life cycle of objects is not managed by a garbage collector but by [scopes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) even the smart pointers. So my take on this is, learn C++ from the bottom up a bit first before trying to translate Java code into C++ code. And even then it is best to just understand only the algorithm and reimplement it in C++

Comment: *Coming from the Java world, this code works as desired:* -- *However in C++* -- It doesn't really make sense to show Java code.  Java and C++ are two different languages with different idioms.   Note that most of the comments suggest rewrites or redesigns of the code.  The way you "convert" Java to C++ is 1) Know both languages,  2) Figure out what the Java code is doing,  3) Throw away the Java code and write the C++ code using C++ idioms and best practices.  Doing line-by-line translations from Java to C++ will end in tears most of the time.

Comment: Good sources to learn C++ from are a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (make sure it is up-to-date and not teaching you "C"). Or you can use  [learncpp.com](https://learncpp.com/). Also make sure to check [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to explore what C++ has to offer (containers/algorithms). 
And finally refer to the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to learn how C++  is intended to be used.

Comment: Also freely using std::shared_ptr in C++ can lead to a cyclic dependency that cannot be removed (deleted)

Comment: Given that this is supposed to be a directed *acyclic* graph, there shouldn't be any cycles, which is what would lead to memory leaks with `shared_ptr`...

Comment: note that you'll need to change some of your `shared_ptr`s to `weak_ptr`s to prevent cylces and memory leaks

Comment: @AlanBirtles: under what circumstance would you need a `weak_ptr` to prevent a cycle in a directed **acyclic** graph?

Comment: @JerryCoffin the datastructure might be assumed to be a DAG, but I don't see any check that invariant (being acyclic) is maintained or checked. Adding a child node should check for that

Comment: @JerryCoffin I've not examined the code in detail but nodes have a list of parents and children, I'm assuming that therefore there is a cycle between a parent node and it's child?

Comment: @PepijnKramer: I agree that it should. And honestly, ruakh's advice to have the graph own all the nodes, and each node have non-owning pointers to other nodes is probably good. But whatever problem you have in modeling a DAG, a weak_ptr is *probably* the wrong solution.

Comment: @AlanBirtles: The code doesn't currently do anything to prevent cycles, which would lead to leaks. But a leak wouldn't lead the symptoms he describes. In any case, given that it's supposed to be modeling a DAG, if a cycle was detected, the reasonable response would be an error message, not a `weak_ptr`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin the graph itself may be acyclic but the data structure in the code is definitely not. `AbstractDAGNode` adds itself to the `parents` list of each of its children, the children are held by `shared_ptr` and the parents are `shared_ptr`s too so there is a cycle. I wasn't suggesting the cycle was the cause of the problem hence it was a comment and not an answer and was prefixed with "note". The answer to the question is in the duplicate, the note was pre-empting the next issue in the code

Comment: 1) Appreciate all the answers! (except from those that I should learn C++ from scratch, not translate from Java line-by-line, etc. - well, I'm not translating from Java, this was just to demonstrate that I do have a conceptual understanding of how to code up DAG with tools I'm already fluent in; in Python it was even simpler).

Comment: 2) Checking a cycle is a potential issue but that wasn't part of the argument. Having an adjacency matrix is possible but it changes the design completely. I could implement DAG using arrays and raw pointes (more C-like style), but that's also not what I'm trying to learn here. So `weak_ptr` looks like an option, but where should I use them here to make it work?

Comment: @AlanBirtles: yes, it contains pointers from children to parents--but I'd posit this fits with: "whatever problem you have in modeling a DAG, a `weak_ptr` is probably the wrong solution."